Different time trends of groups: quadratic vs. linear decline
Suppose we have two groups of individuals A and B that we observe over time on a parameter, say blood pressure.
We want to compare the group effect over time in a GLMM using lme4, but A and B behave differently over time. While the level of aggression in group A decreases linearly, the level of aggression in group B decreases quadratically (or logarithmically).
My question is: Is it possible to account for these time trends?
I am only familiar with modeling quadratic terms for both groups, as in
lmer(blood_pressure ~ time + group * I(time^2) + (time + I(time^2) | ID)).
I thought this might be important to include in the model, but maybe I am completely off track?

If you know/want to assume a priori that group A and group B follow time trends with different functional forms, you can hack it by using a dummy variable/indicator variable for each group. You can either construct these yourselves (mydata$dummyA <- as.numeric(mydata$group == "A")) or use the dummy() function from lme4, i.e. dummy(mydata$group, "A"), e.g.
blood_pressure ~ 1 + group + dummyA:(poly(time, 2)) + 
    dummyB:(log(time)) +
    (0 + dummyA + dummyA:(poly(time, 2))|group) +
    (0 + dummyB + dummyB:(log(time)|group))

This particular example fits a separate variance term for each group.
I don't know that I would necessarily recommend this strategy, though, unless you have some fairly specific ideas about the data: why not fit a full quadratic model (or cubic spline)-by-group interaction and allow the model to (for example) estimate that the quadratic term is small for one group?
The second part of this question would be how to do inference on (say) the average trend when the shape/functional form of the trend differs between groups. Here I think emmeans::emtrends() will do what you want, by constructing a reference grid and computing (and comparing) slopes between groups averaged across the grid.

Thanks, @Ben Bolker! I figured it would only make sense to account for the time trends if the two groups were substantially different. My procedure would have been: a) test the shape of the time trend of each group individually b) account for these shapes in a joint analysis. I can imagine that this is not statistically clean, since inspection and testing are done on the same data set, but this is a fairly new area of research, so the results need to be replicated anyway. From what you're saying, though, it sounds like it shouldn't make much of a difference whether I account for shapes or not?

IMO if you're concerned about shape differences/allowing for shape differences you should use a method that's flexible enough to handle different shapes for different groups (e.g. a GAM that allows different curves by group). Testing/selecting/fitting sounds complicated and (as you point out) snoop-y. But it's a much broader question - depends on your specific problem and your goals (prediction? inference?)
